# Error "A type load exception has occurred." using apns-sharp with mono

Tags: c#, monodevelop, apple-push-notifications, typeloadexception, apns-sharp

I'm trying to move my APN backoffice from PHP to C# for performance issue. Bear with me, I'm new to C# and mono.

I've just downloaded MonoDevelop 2.8.6.4 and APNS-sharp merge 26 on my OSX 10.7.2

I opened the entire solution with all libraries and test executables and built the entire solution without errors. I modified the fields (token id, cert file, ...) in the Program.cs in JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications.Test to meet my specs.
After a few tries I managed to get my certificate file OK and the connection to Apple servers is now up. I see the message saying I'm connected in the output of the application.

Probleme comes now. Everytime the application tries to send a message to Apple I get the error "A Type load exception has occured". I tried a little debug and the error seems to come from the NotificationPayload constructor.

Doing step by step follow up, it appears the NotificationAlert is correctly instantiated inside the NotificationPayload constructor. The error appears when coming back to the Notification constructor where the Payload member appears in the debugger as "A type load exception has occurred." instead of an object.

From there the Notification object ends up with the same behavior.

From my research on the Internet this could come from the version of Newtonsoft.Json.Compact.dll but I have no idea what to do with this piece of information.

For information I can see the same error when running the compiled test on my CentOS server.

And for more information the application message (changed ex.Message to ex.ToString() in the test program to get a full error) :

```
Notification Queued!
Sleeping 15000 milliseconds before next Notification...
Connecting...
Connected...
Error: System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
at JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications.Notification.ToBytes () [0x0006c] in /Users/laurent/Downloads/Redth-APNS-Sharp-595275f 2/JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications/Notification.cs:90 
at JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications.NotificationChannel.Send (JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications.Notification notification) [0x00000] in /Users/laurent/Downloads/Redth-APNS-Sharp-595275f 2/JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications/NotificationChannel.cs:371 
at JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications.NotificationConnection.workerMethod () [0x00035] in /Users/laurent/Downloads/Redth-APNS-Sharp-595275f 2/JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications/NotificationConnection.cs:381
```

I didn't put the code, as I didn't change anything from the one you can see at https://github.com/Redth/APNS-Sharp.

I send an SOS to all mono guru around.

Have a nice day fellow developers and thanks in advance for your help and time. Any suggestion is gladly welcome.

Comment: `TypeLoadException` suggests that you haven't got all the dependencies you need. Can you not get any more information from the exception? There's likely to be a nested one...

Comment: Hi Jon, I'd love to harvest more information about the exception but I have no idea how to do so. Any quick idea ? I did say I was new to mono and C# :-( #shame

Comment: Well, what's swallowing the exception? If it's in some open source code, you could always modify that...

Comment: The code dealing with the error is  this one: `static void service_Error(object sender, Exception ex)
  {
   Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Error: {0}", ex.Message));
  }`

Comment: Right - change that code to print `ex` rather than `ex.Message`; you'll get a lot more information that way.

Comment: The code dealing with the error is  this one: `static void service_Error(object sender, Exception ex)
  {
   Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Error: {0}", ex.Message));
  }`  Can I do better than ex.ToString() to get info? Or should I modify the way i call the constructor to intercept the first exception and get info ? How should i do that? try/catch?

Comment: I changed from `Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Error: {0}", ex.ToString()));` to `Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Error: {0}", ex));` but message remains the same

Comment: I may be wrong but it seems like the exception is caught when trying to use the object that didn't successfully instantiated rather than when it actually fails in instantiating.

Comment: But either way you've got an exception... I'd expect the whole stack trace to be printed...

Comment: Well I guess the problem don't come from the instantiation. I added a try and catch around the `Payload = new NotificationPayload();` and it doesn't catch anything. The only way to see the error before it appears in the logs is by checking the content of my object in debug mode, either by following the variable or by mousing over it. I'm wondering if it isn't the fact of checking the value of the object that throws the exception ...

Comment: Well solution found, I had to download a new version of Newtonsoft.Json.Compact.dll. I'll mark my question as answered as soon as i'm allowed to !

Comment: You'll have to add an answer in order to have something to mark as accepted :)

Comment: Yep but I'm not allowed to post one yet ...

Comment: Okay - I've added an answer... let me know if there's anything else you'd like me to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As the OP can't post the answer himself...)

In this particular case, the solution was to fetch the latest version of  `Newtonsoft.Json.Compact.dll`.

In general, you need to try to get as much information from the exception as possible, to find out what it was trying to load - then check that the problematic library is present, and that you've got the version everything else expects.